# What is the software to create this type of anime?

Tags: anime-production

This site is have an beatiful anime style: [Tofugu.com](http://tofugu.com/)

Anyone know what is the software to draw [this anime](http://www.tofugu.com/2014/03/13/why-the-japanese-education-system-does-not-excel-as-much-as-you-might-think/) style?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about creating your own anime and manga. Which is deemed off-topic per the [help].

Comment: The art in question is not from anime/manga, not doujinshi, not anime/manga fanart, and not in a recognizablely anime-ish art style. That being said, the illustrator can be contacted with inquiries at: http://www.tofugu.com/about/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the software is mostly independent of the style. The style depent on how the artist is drawing it...

Anyway it is not always possible to redraw a image because the software is not supporting some functions! The style from the website you linked is pretty simple so you do not need something special.

[image: Example Image]

It would be possible to draw the image above with the standard paint of windows except the cheeks (if you look closely a special brush was used to draw this). But this is absolutely not suggested if you really want to redraw it.

The image is very likly drawn with a tablet that supports pressure/speed recognition (recognizable at the fading outlines) and a software that supports paint application modes (recognizable at the shadows/lightning) and also layer support (the green/yellow background is one layer and the girl with the table and the chair is at least one layer).

Such things are mostly supported on a reasonably good painting software:

- [Adobe Photoshop](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop.html) (monthly payment)
- [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) (open source)
- [PaintTool SAI](http://www.systemax.jp/en/sai/) (pay once)
- [Anime/Manga Studio](http://manga.smithmicro.com/) (pay once)
- [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/index.html) (free to use) <sub>I am not sure if everything is possible in this software I listed above!</sub>

Comment: Thank you, Gerret! You must be a super expert in this field. :) So Photoshop can be, then i will try to learn draw this style. Thank again!

Comment: @user3865184 Well I wish I am! I know this because I am interested in drawing and editing but this is only theory. Sometimes I draw some anime/manga but I am not really good at it... But I am glad that I could help you! :D